# Explanations and examples for pytest cache mechanism

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

Can someone please help me understand how to write a python code that uses the pytest cache? The only example I was able to find was: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/cache.html and https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#std-fixture-cache and I could not understand much of it. Must I have a fixture? In addition, is this cache thread safe? (no dataraces)? thanks.